# Any SQL Server 2008 Database Change Management (MIgrations) Tools Available?

Tags: sql-server-2008, nant, tarantino

We were running [Tarantino](http://code.google.com/p/tarantino/wiki/DatabaseChangeManagement) in a Nant build script but we're getting some new hardware and using the opportunity to upgrade to SQL Server 2008. Unfortunately Tarantino won't work with SQL 2K8 so I'm looking for an alternative.

Any ideas?

Comment: Which tool did you use in the end?

Comment: @DavidAtkinson we used [Tarantino](http://code.google.com/p/tarantino/wiki/DatabaseChangeManagement) for that project. Using the built in Entity Framework bits now.

Comment: Code-first migrations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Migrator.net](http://code.google.com/p/migratordotnet/) is the tool I use with SQL 2008. It also has nant script capability. I suggest using the trunk version, rather than the 0.7 release as it's had some good, as yet unreleased changes.

[This](http://flux88.com/blog/net-database-migration-tool-roundup/) roundup has other options. And there are [few](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/313/-net-migrations-engine) [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8033/database-migration-library-for-net) similar questions here.

Comment: what are the unreleased features ? I'm using MIgrator.NET as well, and I've written some extension methods for some functionality I wanted ...

Comment: I started out using 0.7.0 just fine. I changed for Fluent interface, a load of fixes and dry-run/script option but mostly for long (non-incremental) Migration attributes which is good for branches.

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a few really good tools - some require adoption of a database change management process (like [DBGhost](http://www.dbghost.com/)), while others are less restrictive, but require more work (and efforts) on your side, e.g. Red-Gate's [SQL Packager](http://www.red-gate.com/products/SQL_Packager/index.htm), which allows you to package your database creation and change scripts into .NET projects and/or stand-alone EXE files.

Comment: I've used DbGhost for 10 years and it's never let me down. The support they provide is second to none.

Answer (score 0):

I believe Tarantino has been fixed now to work with SQL2008 as of March 2009

http://code.google.com/p/tarantino/source/list

Answer (score 0):

Try the [latest version](http://code.google.com/p/tarantino/source/browse/trunk/LatestVersion/Tarantino.zip) of Tarantino from SVN, it works with SQL Server 2008.
Unfortunately, they have an outdated release published in Downloads section.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to have a look at [RoundhousE](http://projectroundhouse.org) as well.